# GNUPLOT- Plotting a bar-graph with a .txt file

Tags: gnuplot

We have to plot a bar-graph using GNUplot and Idk how to do that. We have two .txt files but I only need help for one of them. We have to label the x axis (Age group) with 3 columns 35-49, 50-64, 65+ and label the y axis (percentage of diabetes). Please help me, THANK YOU!

Below is the data inside the .txt file:

```
Age Group       Percentage%
35-49             4.1%
50-64             10.3%
65+               18.2%
```

I was able to set the title of the x and y axis but idk how to start actually plotting the bar graph.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What have you tried so far? Have you done any search, e.g. on the gnuplot homepage, on StackOverflow or in gnuplot tutorials or checked the manual? Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: In the gnuplot console type `help boxes` or check the PDF manual in the gnuplot docs directory.

Answer (score 0):

The vertical bar graph will be drawn using the plotting style called `boxes`, which draws a box for a given pair of x and y.

But your data does not have a value for x. In such cases, you can use a special column number called 'pseudo column' which can be used in 'using'. If you give pseudo column 0 in `using`, it will set integer value that is automatically incremented by one from 0. Moreover, use the data option `skip 1` to skip a header line of data.

```
set xrange [-0.5:2.5]
set yrange [0:20]

plot "data.txt" skip 1 using 0:2 with boxes fill solid 0.5
```

[image]

Next, for the label for each column, you can use the function `xticlabels` (`xtic` for short), which is used in `using`. In the case of your data, you want to use the string in the first column for the labels of bars, so you will use xtic(1).

```
set xrange [-0.5:2.5]
set yrange [0:20]

plot "data.txt" skip 1 using 0:2:xtic(1) with boxes fill solid 0.5
```

[image]

Now all that is left to do is to make it look better.

```
unset key

set xrange [-0.5:2.5]
set yrange [0:20]
set xlabel "Age Group"
set ylabel "Percentage%"

set origin 0.1,0.1
set size 0.8,0.8

set border 3
set tics nomirror scale 0
set grid ytics
set boxwidth 0.5

plot "data.txt" skip 1 using 0:2:xtic(1) with boxes fill solid 0.5
```

[image]